# VS code show all my hidden lines of code. How can I disable it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**[Problem]**

When edit python code in vs code (visual studio code), the editor show all my hidden lines in my code.

**[Problem procedure]**

(Fig. a) test python code

(Fig. b) I click left blank space of the function name.
Then, I can hide lines of code.

(Fig. c)
I type """ in the editor.
Then, the editor automatically add another """ at the end of the line.

**(Fig. d) I cut(ctrl+x) automatically added """.

Then, All of my hidden lines are opened. This is the problem.**

[I call each figures as (a),(b),(c),(d) from left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xilJj.png)

**[Question]**

I would like to open "my hidden lines" only when I click it.